# What is the need of assigning 'nil' after releasing an object

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-management

I usually release the object after use by

```
[myObject release];
```

But I found in some online tutorials that they assign a **nil** after releasing the object. Like

```
[myObject release];
myObject = nil;
```

Is it required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why set object to nil after sending release message in Obj-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072003/why-set-object-to-nil-after-sending-release-message-in-obj-c)

Comment: Other candidates: [Set pointers to nil after release](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1418999/) [Is it necessary to set pointers to nil after release](http://stackoverflow.com/q/803531/) [When to set object references to nil](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1670876/) [Difference between release and release, then set to nil](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2809603/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a long-running debate as to whether setting the pointer to `nil` after releasing is necessary, but I come down on the side of it being a good idea.

After the object is released, the pointer you hold to it still points to the same place. If your release has taken the retain count to 0 then the object will be deallocated. If you then try and send a message to the deallocated object you'll get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. However, sending a message to the pointer after it's been set to `nil` won't error - it just won't do anything.

The other side of the argument is that if you're messaging a deallocated object it's good to know about it and fix your code to make sure it doesn't happen.

There are smart people in both camps.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not strictly required. 
If your code is well-structured there's no need to force `myObject` to be equal to nil.

However it may be a good habit: `release` does not immediately destroy the object, just decrease the `retain` count. Thus it may be,that, even if you call release, the object will still be there for a while, creating problems if you try to send it messages.

Using `myObject = nil;` eliminate this problem, since, even if you send a message to `myObject` nothing will actually happen.

Comment: I can only add this [great blog post by Jeff Lamarche](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/dealloc.html). Which is an interesting read.

Comment: If the retain count would go to zero on a release the object is destroyed. But the memory is not cleared so it may appear to still be there. Only the pointer value is set to zero. The protection is that if another part of the code is referencing through the pointer and the pointer is nil nothing bad will happen, note that this covered a bug in the code!. There is another possibility, assign (id)0x42 so that there will be an immediate crash if there is an accede through the pointer by error,then the code can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not required, but mostly a style issue. Assigning `nil` after the release ensures, that you cannot accidentally use the released reference again (which may or may not result in a crash). Simply calling `release` on the reference may make the underlying memory go away. However, the pointer will still point to the (now potentially invalid) address, and the result of a subsequent method invocation using that pointer are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not required.

It's a safety thing. If you have

```
[myObject release];
```

and then somewhere else you do

```
[myObject doSomething];
```

Then you will get problems.

If you have

```
[myObject release];
myObject = nil;
```

and then somewhere else you do

```
[myObject doSomething];
```

Then nothing will happen because you are calling on a nil object. So your app won't just fall over in a big heap. Or if you then have somewhere else in the code

```
[myObject release];
```

Then it will release on a nil object and so won't over-release.

Obviously you should just avoid calling on an object that you have already released!

Answer (score 2):

**I would always set to nil.**

**Apple themselves sometimes (documented) check for nil.**

**Example;**

If you set the `navigationItem.titleView` needs to be set back to `nil` if you want to revert back to using `navigationItem.title`, or your title will not be displayed.

There are lots of references to this "nil checking" in the Apple documentation.

Reference;

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html

[Restoring navigationItem.title after removing navigationItem.titleView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470096/restoring-navigationitem-title-after-removing-navigationitem-titleview)

Answer (score 1):

not really, but better to use it to prevent errors...

if you call somewhere in your code myObject when it's been release it give you a bad error,
but if it's stetted to nil the error may by bypassed

if you try:

```
myObject.someProperty = 1;
```

or

```
if (myObject) {...}
```

and you just released myObject, it just could crash your app...

Answer (score 1):

It is not required, but it is generally considered to be good practice in all environments, with the exception that it is generally considered unnecessary in a `-dealloc` method.

The reason it is common to set the object pointer to nil after release is because the Objective-C method dispatcher will not try to send a message to a nil object, which means that you're safe to accidentally use the object later.

Answer (score 0):

after release an abject but not assign NULL, it keeps the address but content is deallocated. So now it is not pointing to any valid memory location.Hence ptr is now dangling pointer which probably having a address but not pointing to any valid memory location.
so it is good practice to assign NULL after freeing the allocated memory as below

ptr=NULL;

in this way dangling problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a hybrid approach. Let us look at the typical app requirements:

1. We want to minimize application crashes in production
2. We want to catch problems like accessing potentially released memory, while we are testing

A good solution is to conditionally assign to:

1. Nil in release builds
2. An intentionally bad pointer (e.g. 0x20) in debug.

This brings stability in production builds, but in debug mode any attempt to access the variable will explicitly crash the application. Please note that calling release on an object does not guarantee that the object memory will be deleted hence the need to explicitly set to bad pointer.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define RELEASE(obj) [(obj) release]; (obj) = (id)0x20;
#else
    #define RELEASE(obj) [(obj) release]; (obj) = nil;
#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

At an Apple Tech Talk I went to a couple of years ago the Apple engineers discussed a few instances where it was essential to assign to nil, but I can't recall the details other than it was inside dealloc in the instances discussed. Suffice it to say that it's not correct to say that you never have to or that it's bad-practice to do so. Sometimes you have to. But most times you don't have to. Sorry my memory isn't clearer.